# how to check all values in particular column has same data type or not?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, numpy

I have column 'ABC' which has 5000 rows. Currently, dtype of column is object. Mostly it has string values but some values dtype is not string, I want to find all those rows and modify those rows. Column is as following:

```
1 abc
2 def
3 ghi
4 23
5 mno
6 null
7 qwe
8 12-11-2019
...
...
...
4900 ert
5000 tyu
```

In above case, I can use for loop to find out rows which do not have desired dtype. I just wanted to know, is their better way to solve this issue.

Note: I am using Pandas.

Comment: In pandas dtypes can be inferred by trying to cast them and making un-castable ones to string dtypes as in `object`, which means all elements in a single column will be in a same datatype. You cant have two diff. row elements in the same column to be of different datatypes.

Comment: @KiriteeGak: I think that is not quite true. You can test that yourself. Create a dataframe, with at least two rows indexed 1 and 2. Then do `df.loc[1, 'new_column']= 'my_value'`. Then do `df['new_column'].map(type)`. You will see, that all but the first row contain `float`s. That is because the other rows contain `NaN`, which is a `float` and not a `str`. Likewise you could mix in other object types in your `object` column if you like (but it is probably not a very good idea).

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can get the type of the entries of your column with map:

```
df['ABC'].map(type)
```

So to filter on all values, which are not stored as str, you can use:

```
df['ABC'].map(type) != str
```

If however you just want to check if some of the rows contain a string, that has a special format (like a date), you can check this with a regex like:

```
df['ABC'].str.match('[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}')
```

But of course, that is no exact date check. E.g. it would also return `True` for values like `0000-13-91`, but this was only meant to give you an idea anyways.

Comment: Your method is so powerful! 
I tested with this:
r = [pd.to_datetime('12-11-2019'),1.0,'23',1,2,3,'Hello','2019-11-12']
and returns:
0    <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timesta...
1                                      <class 'float'>
2                                        <class 'str'>
3                                        <class 'int'>
4                                        <class 'int'>
5                                        <class 'int'>
6                                        <class 'str'>
7                                        <class 'str'>